# iOS 7 tiny progress bar can be changes as iOS6 style?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiprogressview

My iOS app was working on iOS 6 but when you build the app with xcode 5 using iOS7 device the progress bar style is changed and I can't return it as previous iOS6 style or even to change the height of the Progress View (Progress Bar). Is there any way to change the style of progress bar? I can see only default and bar in xcode.

Comment: I'm targeting app for iOS4.1+ using iOS7 SDK. if i build the app with xcode 4 it's seems to be OK.

Comment: What are the values in the "Interface Builder Document" panel when you're viewing your .XIB file? See: http://imgur.com/MGt8cXT

Comment: i tried to target xcode 4.6 and xcode 5 but it's same on iOS7 device, when i try it ok iOS6 it's ok.

Comment: Under iOS 7, progress views are real thin. The same app run on iOS 6 will look like it always has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard `UIKit` object. It will appear as it should on each system.

If you don't like the small bar in iOS 7, you should customise it.

You can do so quite easily with `UIAppearance` proxy but you'll need to do so with images, pretty simple, just make your images look like iOS 6, and you should get what you expect.

The properties you'll want to customise should be:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage* progressImage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage* trackImage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the height of my UIProgressView directly in xib. I changed the style to Bar and loaded 2 images, one to progress image and  other to track image. Worked for me.
I hope it helps.